# Find out if a Class explicitly declares implementing a particular interface

Tags: java

For the given Interface `IfA` with class `A` implementing it and class `B` extending `A`, I'd like to determine which of both classes `A` and `B` explicitly declare implementing the interface `IfA`.

Obviously `IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)` and `IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` are both `true`. I hoped for a Method like

`B.class.declaresInterface(IfA.class)` -> `false`

`A.class.declaresInterface(IfA.class)` -> `true`

But something like this does not exist, does it?

---

Background: from some variable `Class<? extends IfA> x`; not knowing if it is A, B or some other class C extending A or B ... I'd like to search the upper most super class implementing the interface. Currently I'm implying a somewhat ugly search for this:

```
public class SomeTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testIt() {
        assertTrue(IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class));
        assertTrue(IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class));

        Class<? extends IfA> b = B.class;

        Class<?> result = b;

        // somewhat ugly search: from B.class find A.class
        while (IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getSuperclass())) {
            result = result.getSuperclass();
        }

        Object s = result.getSuperclass();

        assertSame(A.class, result);
        assertFalse(IfA.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getSuperclass()));
    }

    interface IfA {
    };

    class A implements IfA {
    };

    class B extends A {
    };
}
```

Is there a more explicity way of interface detection, making the search easier to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik there's no `declaresInterface(...)` method in the JDK itself although there might be a library that provides one.

The `Class` class itself provides the a method called [`getInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()) which according to the JavaDoc:

> Returns the interfaces directly implemented by the class or interface represented by this object.

Thus an implementation for `boolean declaresInterface(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> interface )` should be quite straight forward (though performance might be improved using some caching):

```
boolean declaresInterface(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> iface) {
  //note: you should add some checks, e.g. for null and correct types
  return Arrays.stream( clazz.getInterfaces() )
               .anyMatch( iface::equals );
}
```

Tests:

```
//true because Integer implements Comparable<Integer>
declaresInterface( Integer.class, Comparable.class ); 

//false, because Integer extends Number and Number implements Serializable
declaresInterface( Integer.class, Serializable.class );
```

Comment: I've so overseen this `getInterface` method .. thank you very much for your help! Btw: you can shorten the declaresInterfaces method a bit by: `.stream( clazz.getInterfaces() )
               .anyMath( iface::equals );`

Comment: @Selaron that's true, missed that method :) - I'll update the answer